# With minimal experience from external APIs, yet enough experience with the Java Core API, is it worth looking to answer questions?

Tags: discussion

I enjoy helping on SO. However the only programming language I consider myself well taught in to help out on SO is java, and the core Java API, yet other than the Minecraft Spigot API I have no knowledge on external APIs (such as Android, Google Maps, SQL...). I find it a bit difficult to find questions on SO regarding the Java API (without SQL), and those that do are usually marked duplicates. Now, my question today, as seen in the title.

**With minimal experience from external APIs, yet enough experience with the Java Core API, is it worth looking to answer questions?**

Usually I do 10-15 minutes of searching and occasionally see a question I can give a good answer on, but if I devoted a bit more time to SO, in my current state (with the minimal experience, though of course gradually my experience will improve), will I find questions that I can give good, helpful answers on regularly?

Like I said, eventually I probably will have helpful knowledge of SQL, the Android API, or other common APIs, but that won't be for a long time I imagine, and that has brought me to my question today on whether until that while comes my time here on SO will be helpful to others.

Comment: I've answered questions about APIs I've never used in my life - heck, a couple of times even *programming languages* - using nothing but some Googling and some of my general programming experience. (Of course, questions that can be *totally* easily Googled should likely be closed rather than answered.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We all had to start some here on Stack Overflow, so I would say write an answer where you can contribute.

If no one else has answered then your answer, even if not complete, might provide the piece of information that the questioner needs. Your answer might provide the piece of information that someone else needs to write a great answer. In either case you have helped others.

If there are already answers then only add your answer if it is better or more comprehensive than the others. Or, if it fills in gaps that the others have missed.